# Return a numpy array from a function without brackets [] python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array output from this command:
print(function(8,8))

```
[['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']  
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']  
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']  
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']  
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']  
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']  
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']  
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-' '-']]
```

I'd like to have the function return the array without any brackets or '', like the following.

print(function(8,8))

```
--------   
--------  
--------    
--------    
--------    
--------    
--------    
--------
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What does it mean to have an *array without any brackets or "*?

Comment: `for line in function(8,8): print(''.join(line))` ?

Comment: You are seeking a string, not an array.

Comment: is it a constant character in the array?

Answer (score 1):

```
def format_array(a):
    return "\n".join( [''.join( x ) for x in a] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
def function(n,m):
  return ('-'*m+'\n')*n
```

or if you have an array with a constant character:

```
def function(array):
  return (array[0,0]*array.shape[1]+'\n')*array.shape[0]
```

You can also change/pass the character you want to print to the function.

```
print(function(8,8))
--------
--------
--------
--------
--------
--------
--------
--------
```